# Difficult on modeling human head

Tags: modeling

**Blender version**: 4.0.2

I was trying to sculpt a simple human head for future animations using two planes: one for the face and ears, and one for the back. I am starting low-poly. I use multiresolution for verifying how things are playing out.

I was using mostly the edit mode to build everything, not much of the sculpt mode. I have recorded some of the initial [modeling process](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3S2rJSg4NlCEPW51fZG2ICMuwgK4RxtH), but, you see, the results aren't that nice.

Importantly, I am having two issues: the ear looks distorted, and the head looks like it is split or was sewn.

[image: Sewn head]

[image: Distorted ear]

*Note: I may probably restart all this head.*

[image: Low-poly]

[image]

Comment: there is [box modelling](https://youtu.be/GigCYmV3Ups?) and there is sculpting. For both approaches it's a good idea to start with a cube or a sphere. The *MultiRes* modifier is like a layer to add fine details like wrinkles if you have a base model done. It's *not* used to turn a cube into a human head. Better use the *remesh* operation when you sculpt the mesh to create the base shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faces on the back of the head have inverted normals. On the <kbd>Viewport</kbd><kbd>Overlay</kbd> dropdown enable <kbd>Face</kbd><kbd>Orientation</kbd>. The red portion shows that the normals are flipped. Blue is ok.

Go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, select <kbd>A</kbd>ll then <kbd>Shift-N</kbd> to recalculate the Normals.

[image]

There are still a couple of faces on the ear which are inverted but I think you should start again with that anyway as the topology is very poor. You also need to add and apply a Subdivision Surface modifier to give the sculpt brushes more vertices to work on.