# Subdivision resulting into camel mount and spike

Tags: modeling

Following [Difficult on modeling human head](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/315691/185385), I have followed a bit of the [box modelling tutorial](https://youtu.be/GigCYmV3Ups?) mentioned in the comments.

The head I got has a similiar issue at two points; there's a spike and a "camel mount" in two different places, near the nose and above at the head.

With Face Normalization:

[image: Face Normalization]

With Subdivision Surface 4x:

[image: Subdivision Surface]

If I adjust more the back of the head, it doesn't still solve the "camel mount" issue:

[image: Adjustment]

I did not need to recalculate the Normals as the answer points since I have used a cube to build the head. First I added a cube, then applied only one Subdivision Surface and followed the tutorial until after the Modelling a Jaw chapter.

X-Ray enabled:

[image: X-Ray Enabled]

[image]

Comment: Please consider uploading your file with https://blend-exchange.com/. It could be because of double vertices : in *Edit Mode*, press A, right-click *Merge Vertices > By Distance* ?

Comment: @Lutzi I have added it. Unfortunately, not double vertices!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have internal geometry, creating artifacts when combined with *Subdivision Surface*.

- Go to *Edit Mode* with <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Set *Viewport Shading* to *Wireframe* with <kbd>Z</kbd>
- Be sure x-ray is on with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- Select the 2 inner vertices, near the nose and forehead
- Delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> *> Vertices*

Before and after :

[image: Before and after removing 2 bad vertices]